# Ошибка Makefile:38

Tags: linux, shell

При создании переменной настройки программы

```
STANDALONE_TOOLCHAIN=path/to/android-ndk-r11c/sysroot-arm/bin make
```

Терминал выдает ошибку:

```
make: path/to/android-ndk-r11c/sysroot-arm/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++: Команда не найдена
Makefile:38: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «rh-test.o»
make: *** [rh-test.o] Ошибка 127
```

Действия выполняю последовательно в соответствии с образцом с GitHub:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r11c-linux-x86_64.zip
unzip android-ndk-r11c-linux-x86_64.zip
cd android-ndk-r11c
./build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --ndk-dir=`pwd` \
  --arch=arm --platform=android-24 \
  --install-dir=./sysroot-arm/ \
  --verbose
```

Comment: написано же: «команда не найдена». если имеется такой файл, то либо у него нет битов исполнимости (для вашего пользователя), либо файловая система, на которой он расположен, смонтирована с опцией `noexec` (другие причины менее вероятны).

Comment: вместо `path/to` надо указать «путь к» тулчейну (компилятор/make/что-там ещё нучжо-для-сборки) в своей системе